# Book about a girl raised by a robot

Tags: story-identification

When I was in middle school I remember reading a lovely book about a girl who was raised by a robot. She has braids and there was artwork at the beginning of each chapter. She has to escape her home when an alien attacks her home, I think it was looking for her because she was the last human? Her "mother" robot (I remember it had a name like mother, but it stood for something) is broken and she travels either looking for a way to fix her with a very tall alien or to look for the people on the cover of her old book that has a robot, girl, and an alien on the cover.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193332/young-adult-novel-about-a-girl-with-a-robot-housekeeper-on-an-alien-planet (which has an OP comment confirming it is correct)

Answer (score 6):

I think this might be *[The Search for WondLa](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7327327-the-search-for-wondla)* by Tony DiTerlizzi, first published in 2009.

[image: The Search for WondLa - book cover - redhaired girl stares wistfully to one side with alien creatures depicted below her and a robot face at the bottom]

> Eva Nine is a curious and sensitive twelve-year-old who has existed only in a subterranean home called Sanctuary, cared for by a robot named Muthr. Eva's great desire is to go aboveground, and her wish comes true, though not as she had imagined. On the surface, Eva goes in search of other humans--she has never met one--and soon meets both friend and foe.

[One of the reviews](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1787239934?book_show_action=true) mentions the attack

> Eva Nine's house goes under siege by a a large monster-like hunter and everything she knows is destroyed. She must make her way in a new world and find where she came from and maybe make some interesting friends along the way.

There are illustrations mentioned in that review, and they can be found online.

> I can't talk about this book without talking about Tony DiTerrlizzi's beautiful illustrations. They are through-out the book and they add such a wonderful element to the reading experience. You get to look at the author's creations through their eyes and I was very happy for it. I wish more books would do this.

[image: Eva Nine stands to one side, hugging a raccoon stuffed toy while Muthr puts one hand on her shoulder. Various toys are lined up across the floor, and an alien landscape is visible through large windows in the background]

This was one of the first books that came up when I searched for *book girl raised by robots*. There are two sequels, *[A Hero for WondLa](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12049592-a-hero-for-wondla)* and *[The Battle For WondLa](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18454480-the-battle-for-wondla)*.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, Grae, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: I remember this book!!