# A girl raised by a robot, utopian children's book

Tags: story-identification, robots, childrens-novel

I can't remember the name, or the author or a lot about the book.

It was a children's book, I read it around 2010-2011, the illustrations were very pretty, almost watercolor-like, a lot of pink and pastel colors.

Most of the story I remember is that the setting was an utopian future, the girl and the robot are in some place resembling a museum.

The robot is a female-like android, she has her eyes covered by a visor, she's part of a line of robots made to raise kids, she can answer and ask questions.

I remember a part where the girl asked about the past, and how children had parents back then, as in this future, kids are artificially conceived and born in incubators to ensure better characteristics, as explained by the robot.

*There are no aliens in the story, it is implied they're in earth, but in the far future

*It was kind of a short book, the illustrations filled the page and had small paragraphs of text

*I'm almost sure the girl had red/pink hair

*I have to point out, i'm mexican, but most children books are a translation of european or american books

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Are there adults in this world at all (maybe offscreen) or are there only kids?  Are there other kids present?  Do you remember what the cover looked like?

Comment: I think there were adults, but none of them important to the story, the cover i think was a drawing of the main human girl, i was 6-7 at the time, i can't remember a lot

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Migh this be *[The Search for WondLa](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7327327-the-search-for-wondla)* by Tony DiTerlizzi, first published in 2009, as per [Book about a girl raised by a robot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175827/book-about-a-girl-raised-by-a-robot/)?

[image: The Search for WondLa - book cover - redhaired girl stares wistfully to one side with alien creatures depicted below her and a robot face at the bottom]

> Eva Nine is a curious and sensitive twelve-year-old who has existed only in a subterranean home called Sanctuary, cared for by a robot named Muthr. Eva's great desire is to go aboveground, and her wish comes true, though not as she had imagined. On the surface, Eva goes in search of other humans--she has never met one--and soon meets both friend and foe.

[One of the reviews](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1787239934?book_show_action=true) mentions the illustrations:

> I can't talk about this book without talking about Tony DiTerrlizzi's beautiful illustrations. They are through-out the book and they add such a wonderful element to the reading experience. You get to look at the author's creations through their eyes and I was very happy for it. I wish more books would do this.

[image: Eva Nine stands to one side, hugging a raccoon stuffed toy while Muthr puts one hand on her shoulder. Various toys are lined up across the floor, and an alien landscape is visible through large windows in the background]

However, as you can see in the image, Muthr does not have a visor.

Comment: And if so, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193332/young-adult-novel-about-a-girl-with-a-robot-housekeeper-on-an-alien-planet has an accepted answer.

Comment: i had checked that same question before! And although i thank you for answering, it is not the book i'm looking for, i really thank you for the attention!